# Can't override property with an inherited version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, inheritance

I have a base `ListFragment` that uses a base `ListPresenter`
On top of that I have `ContactsFragment` (inherits from `ListFragment`) and a `ContactsPresenter` (inherits from `ListPresenter`)

The base `ListFragment` has a `presenter` property which is open and protected
I'm trying to override this property in `ContactsFragment` with a `ContactsPresenter`

For some reason, android studio doesn't detect it has a child class of the `ListFragment`'s `presenter`

**ListFragment**

```
abstract class ListFragment<ItemType, Adapter : ListAdapter<ItemType>> : BaseFragment(),
ListContract.View<ItemType> {

protected open val presenter: ListPresenter<ItemType, ListFragment<ItemType, Adapter>> by lazy {
    ListPresenter(this)
}
...
}
```

**ListPresenter**

```
open class ListPresenter<ItemType, V : ListContract.View<ItemType>>(view: V) : BasePresenter<V>(view),
ListContract.Presenter<ItemType, V> {
...
}
```

**ContactsFragment**

```
class ContactsFragment : ListFragment<Contact, ContactsAdapter>(), ContactsContract.View {

override val presenter: ContactsPresenter<ContactsFragment> by lazy { ContactsPresenter(this) }
...
}
```

**ContactsPresenter**

```
class ContactsPresenter<V : ContactsContract.View>(view: V) : ListPresenter<Contact, V>(view),
ContactsContract.Presenter<V> {
...
}
```

I'm getting this exception annotation:

```
Property type is ContactsPresenter<ContactsFragment>, which is not a subtype type of overridden protected open val presenter: ListPresenter<Contact, ListFragment<Contact, ContactsAdapter>> defined in com.chooloo.www.koler.ui.list.ListFragment
```

But from what I see that assumption is wrong

I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: I didn't take a close look at all these type declarations yet, but it might very well be a [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joffrey I found the solution
Kotlin prohibits this type of behaviour (the one I showed in the question description), since it can't assume if you're going to change the type parameter's related data.
Using the keyword `out`, the kotlin assumes you only consume that type parameter and you can use extended types.

It's called "variance" in kotlin and you can read about it more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

So the final code was the declaration of the `presenter` type in `ListFragment`

```
abstract class ListFragment<ItemType, Adapter : ListAdapter<ItemType>> : BaseFragment(),
ListContract.View<ItemType> {

protected open val presenter: ListPresenter<ItemType, out ListFragment<ItemType, Adapter>> by lazy {
    ListPresenter(this)
}
...
}
```